# Share array between main and window without serialization

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm currently building an electron app.
I'm trying to pass an array from the main process to my main window via the global object

**main.js**

```
global.datas = {values:[1,2,3]}
```

**index.html ( window )**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const remote = electron.remote;
var datas = remote.getGlobal("datas");
```

The problem is that when I get my array, a copy is done with JSON stringify/parse, and when I compare it like this

```
console.log(datas.values === datas.values);
```

it returns false

My question here is, is there a way to share object without serialization ? Just a simple object that is shared between my windows and the main process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't share an object between the main process and the renderer process without serialization.

Comment: Well, it can be annoying with some frameworks using dirty cheks like angularjs. I'm thinking about switching to nw.js. Thanks for the help